# Inheritance with oracle objects

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I try to implement inheritance with Oracle Objects :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ENREG_320_BASE AS OBJECT ( .....) NOT FINAL
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ENREG_320_03 AS OBJECT UNDER ENREG_320_BASE( .....) FINAL
```

I have an error :

> Error: ORA-06550: line 1, column 29: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "UNDER" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( not external JAVA_ BOUND_ The symbol "(" was substituted for
>   "UNDER" to continue. ORA-06550: line 2, column 17: PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol "VARCHAR2" when expecting one of the following:
>
> . ( ) , * @ % & | = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not    range
>   rem => ..  <> or != or ~= >= <= <>    and or like
>   LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKE ORA-06550: line 3, column 27: PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol "VARCHAR2" when expecting one of the following:

Probably there is something I do wrong (first time trying inheritance in PLSQL). Can you help ?

PS : I work with Oracle 10

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need AS OBJECT when creating sub-types.  It's implied by the UNDER keyword.

You should bookmark the documentation in your browser.  It's great for answrering questions like this.  [Find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#sthref199).

Comment: ok because i read some other documentation where it was written like that

Comment: Hmmm, was it official Oracle documentation?  Or just something random you found on the web?